# Extracting data into python list from csv

Tags: python

I have excel sheet with Ids such as je2456,je2645,je2893,....

I would like to save it in a list in python.

But its throwing errors while importing like
'No such file or directory exists.'

Comment: This question does not show enough effort nor does it provide enough details for people to help you. Could you formulate your problem more clearly?

Comment: You're using the wrong filename, or wrong directory name, or both.

Answer (score 0):

### Make sure that the file you are reading from is in the same folder.

```
import csv


def csv_reader(input_file_name):
    with open(input_file_name, newline='') as csvfile:
        return list(csv.reader(csvfile))
```

### Now the call the function and save the output:

```
# Make sure to add the extension for the file name, whatever it may be.
my_data_list = csv_reader("Your_Input_File_Here.csv")
```

Now your `my_data_list` is a list containing all the rows from the CSV file.

Comment: You can just do `all_rows_from_file = list(spamreader)` instead of your loop.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I just updated it, that should be fine right?

Comment: Oh yeah did not need that, duh. Yeah, I have read the pep 8. I just recently have been working a lot with Java/Javascript/C++. Forcing me to do camel casing.